# Base Class Property Inheriting from Base

Tags: c#

I am doing a code review and have stumbled upon a situation where an abstract class is inheriting from an abstract base class that has a property of the inheriting class.

At the moment I am unable to debug the code to see how it would work, but I am assured that this has worked in production for many years.

As such it is a mystery to me how the following logic would work, step by step.

Inheritor:

```
public class Inheritor : Base {
  ...
  properties
  ...
}
```

Base:

```
public class Base {
  public Inheritor { get; set; }
  ...
  other properties
  ...
}
```

How is this possible?

Comment: What logic? This is just a class structure. Why wouldn't an `Animal` class be allowed to have a property of type `Dog`?

Comment: Without seeing how `Inheritor` is initialized in the base class, its entirely possible its null throughout the initialization process which means that its not referenced circularly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An example in which it will hopefully make sense at a conceptual level:

```
public class Boss : Employee {
  ...
  properties
  ...
}

public class Employee {
  public Boss { get; set; }
  ...
  other properties
  ...
}
```

There might be many kinds of employees, but every one might have a boss (who is a particular kind of employee). Recall that properties of non-primitive types are *references*, so it's not the case that an `Employee` contains a `Boss` which (because it is also an `Employee`) contains a `Boss` and so on. An `Employee` *may refer to* a `Boss`, which *may refer to* a `Boss` and so on. At some point, it stops at a `Boss` who doesn't have a `Boss` (the reference is `null`), or it goes in circle.

Comment: And it clicks straight away. Jeez, I don't know how I didn't get how this wasn't more obvious.

Answer (score 3):

I think you may be tripping over the relational concept of **is-a** versus **has-a**, where you are thinking that has-a somehow is constrained in the same way as is-a.  An `Inheritor` is a `Base` and it would be very strange if the reciprocal were true: if a `Base` is also an `Inheritor`.  But no reason why it cannot be that `Base` has an`Inheritor`.